# Microsoft Excel's RAND()

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

Is it possible to use Microsoft Excel's `RAND()` or `RANDBETWEEN()` to obtain specific range of values between say `0.5 and 0.9`?

I know `RAND()` returns random numbers between `0 and 0.999999`, but I would like to avoid values under `0.5` and all `negative numbers`.

I'm guessing it's something obvious but can't put my finger on it.

Comment: `RANDBETWEEN()` only returns integers. Take the result of `RAND()`, multiply by the range (`0.9` - `0.5`) and add the lowest number in the range (`0.5`).

Comment: @ktb please add that as an answer with the actual formula.  It is a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the whole numbers then divide by the number of decimal places

```
=RANDBETWEEN(5,9)/10
```

So if you really want .5000 and .9999 then you would use:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(5000,9999)/10000
```

Comment: Awesome! That works well. Nevermind my edit above :-)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take the result of `RAND()`, multiply by the range (`0.9` - `0.5`) and add the lowest number in the range (`0.5`). Altogether,

```
=(0.9-0.5)*RAND()+0.5
```

Comparing this answer to Scott's, this implementation's domain is all the numbers between the ranges out to maximum precision. But Scott's answer allows you to specify the exact precision you want. Either is a good option, choose which one suits your needs best.

Comment: Yup this was what I was thinking but couldn't get my brain working!
Thanks